# Rails form rendering multiple times if using `.build`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-form-for

So I have a user form `form_for` that accepts nested attributes from account_prices. Whats happening is on my user controller I have this private method.

```
def pre_build_user_account_prices
        if @user.account_prices.empty?
          @accountable_default = @user.account_prices.build(status: 'default')
          @accountable_temporary = @user.account_prices.build(status: 'temporary')
        else
          @accountable_default = @user.account_prices.where(status: 'default')
          @accountable_temporary = @user.account_prices.where(status: 'temporary')
        end
      end
```

reason for the condition is, if I don't do a check here it will render 2 forms. an empty form and with data form. So checking is a need here

---

but my problem is this.Im on edit route, and when I try to submit an invalid form it renders multiple empty forms. heres an image.

### [image]

if I kept submitting invalid form it will render multiple times. I was thinking if checking through JS if theres a multiple child I will remove it. is that the best approach?

here's my asscociations

```
Class User
  has_many :account_prices, as: :accountable, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account_prices
end
```

*polymorphic*

```
 class AccountPrice
      enum status: {default: 'default', temporary: 'temporary'}

      validates :accountable, presence: true
      validates :status, presence: true
      validates :exp_start_date, presence: true, if: :is_temporary_status?
      validates :exp_end_date, presence: true, if: :is_temporary_status?

      belongs_to :accountable, polymorphic: true
      belongs_to :variant_price_set, class_name: "Spree::VariantPriceSet"
      belongs_to :shipping_method_price_set, class_name: "Spree::ShippingMethodPriceSet"

      def is_temporary_status?
        status == 'temporary'
      end

    end
```

*user controller*

```
Class UsersController
  before_action :pre_build_user_account_prices, only: :edit

  def update

        if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
          flash.now[:success] = Spree.t(:account_updated)
          redirect_to show_admin_user_path(@user)
        else
         render :edit
        end
   end

  def pre_build_user_account_prices
        if @user.account_prices.empty?
          @accountable_default = @user.account_prices.build(status: 'default')
          @accountable_temporary = @user.account_prices.build(status: 'temporary')
        else
          @accountable_default = @user.account_prices.where(status: 'default')
          @accountable_temporary = @user.account_prices.where(status: 'temporary')
        end
      end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you're trying `@user.account_prices.where(...` it is reading data which is not persisted to the db too. I mean the account_prices which was just build in the previous step.

Try,

```
def pre_build_user_account_prices
    if @user.account_prices.empty?
      @accountable_default = @user.account_prices.build(status: 'default')
      @accountable_temporary = @user.account_prices.build(status: 'temporary')
    else
      @accountable_default = @user.reload.account_prices.where(status: 'default')
      @accountable_temporary = @user.reload.account_prices.where(status: 'temporary')
    end
end
```

[reload](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reload), reloads the object's attributes from the database

Also, when using accept_nested_attributes for to update an existing entry, you need to make sure that id of the nested object for which you're accepting nested attribute for is part of the attributes passed.

Comment: thanks but its not working. same issue. yes im aware of it. the update works fine but when it starts on an empty record and make a new object and submits an invalid form then it will render multiple forms.

Comment: I think its because of my private method `def pre_build_corp_account_prices` this is being called on edit every time. and if the edit fails it will run the condition and if its empty it will generate a new object. so maybe run it once but is their away to do that?